# Why would mock be adding __nonzero__ method calls?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I've got a bit of code that makes a call to a series of methods on each item in a collection, and each method returns a boolean value indicating success = True/failure = False.

```
def monkey(some_collection, arg1, arg2):
    for item in some_collection:
        if not item.foo(arg1, arg2):
            continue
        if not item.bar(arg1, arg2):
            continue
        if not item.baz(arg1, arg2):
            continue
```

And, here's my unit test example:

```
import mock
def TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_monkey(self):
        item = MagicMock()
        some_collection = [item]
        collection_calls = []
        foo_call = mock.call().foo(some_collection, 1, 2)
        bar_call = mock.call().bar(some_collection, 1, 2)
        baz_call = mock.call().baz(some_collection, 1, 2)
        collection_calls = [foo_call, bar_call, baz_call]                   
        my_module.monkey(some_collection, 1, 2)
        item.assert_has_calls(collection_calls) # requires the correct call order/sequence
```

**Actual Calls**

1. `call().foo(<MagicMock id='12345'>, 1, 2)`
2. `call().foo.__nonzero__()`

...

*NOTE:  This unit test fails because its seeing the `__nonzero__()` method calls.*

**Question**

Why is it adding the nonzero method calls?

**Clarification**

I'm using [mock](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock), which is included in stdlib as of python 3.3.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Short answer:

If your mocked function does not have an explicit return_value or side_effect that returns, you will see this as Python attempts to evaluate the truthiness of your mock. Ensure your mock has one.

Either initialise it with one:

```
item = MagicMock(return_value=True)
```

or add one in:

```
item.return_value = True
```

### Explanation:

When you do `if not x:`, you are probably thinking `if x is False`.

Python doesn't actually do this - it does `if bool(x) is False` (this is Python's *truthiness* concept - that values evaluate to `True` or `False`), and `bool(x)` is actually a call to `x.__nonzero__()` (or `x.__bool__()` in 3.x).

This is to provide Python's nice `if` behaviour - when you do `if []:`, a lot of languages would treat any object as `True`, but Python is designed to make code readable, so it delegates and a list's `__nonzero__()` method will return `False` if it is empty. This allows for more code that reads more naturally, and explains why you will see these calls.

Comment: It's an odd side effect - I get the dunder mechanism, but this is a call to a dunder on the return value of the mock call, not a call to the mocked function/method itself, so it seems a little surprising that it shows here. 

The simple solution is to ensure your mock has an explicit return value - these will then not appear.